# View/Display a PDF's digital signature from command line

Tags: openssl, digital-signature, sha1

I'm trying to learn more about digital signatures, and in the process wanted to try my hand at verifying the authenticity of a signed file. I read that the GPO signs all the documents they host at gpo.gov, so those are the files I've been looking at. Here's one in particular:

http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/search/pagedetails.action?granuleId=&packageId=BUDGET-2013-BUD

I found the public key in the Authenticity Metadate "PREMIS" file that the site links to, but the  node is empty—I assumed that's where I would find the file's signature.

I'm able to create a sha-1 digest of the file using the following command:

```
openssl dgst -sha1 -out digest.txt BUDGET-2013-BUD.pdf
```

My understanding is that to verify a file's authenticity, I need 1) a digest of the file, 2) the signer's public key, and 3) *the signature*, using a command like this (which I found [here](http://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~pcamacho/tutorial/crypto/openssl/openssl_intro.html)):

```
openssl rsautl -verify -in <signature> -out <digest> \
     -inkey <key> -pubin
```

I know that you can use Adobe Reader to verify digitally signed PDFs, but is it also possible to do from the command line? Is there something other than the signature that I should be looking for to accomplish this?

Comment: Digital signature of PDF format is not just an application of RSA algorithm to the file hash, consequently your steps are not applicable. The exception can be if the publisher of your particular PDFs didn't sign them according to PDF format, but just created a signature the way you think.

Comment: Read http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures for more info on digital signatures in PDF files.